# Delphi Application and EV certificate, how to install/configure on Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, certificate, code-signing

Good morning everyone,

we develop a Delphi application for businesses and recently we are facing a lot of problems with the heterogeneous configurations of our customers, in particular with antiviruses and browsers.
Our app is developed for windows, is linked to our support portal (http calls), sync some other infos for some "global environment status" (linked directly to a cloud DB) and use FTP calls to sync requests or docs "to"/"from" the customer.

We've come to the conclusion that to avoid all of these problems we need to "code signign" our app with an EV certificate. Actually I can't find an "How-to" guide that explain to me:

- How to install/configure the cerificate (in delphi XE6)
- If there's some extra steps needed to build/recompile our app before publishing to customers

Any other help would be appreciated, expecially in there's something written the question where I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Additionally to the previous infos, uploading the EXE in virustotal.com none of the 68 engines detect the file as "malicious" or unsafe. Often we can see some slowdowns in the start or during its execution without apparently motivation and shutdowning the antivirus doesn't seems to happen

Comment: Microsoft provides a tool to sign programs. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Comment: You can find a pretty good article about signing Windows Executables [here](https://www.codedotshow.com/blog/delphi-10-3-rio-code-signing-provisioning-and-the-microsoft-app-store/). Note signing of Windows Executables is usually done outside of Delphi environment. Also same proces can be used for any Windows Executable regardless of which Development Environment was used for creating of such Executable.

Comment: I especially like that article as it also covers differences about different certificate4s that can be used for Code Signing of your applications.

Comment: @SilverWarior i've found that article just few days ago, and i've saved into bookmarks because it's very useful, simple and clear. Thanks anyway for the reference.

Comment: So:
1 - there's no need to have the IDE to do the work but i can sign with external App
2 - The extra steps is just to launch the command to sign the exe

Comment: Is there a real needed of an EV certificate instead of an OV certificate? (actually we're a small business)

Comment: You can start a script for signing you app from the post build event inside the IDE.

Comment: No, you don't need an EV certificate. As Ian's article explains, you can use an OV certificate, and the OV cert is much easier to use.